# SQL inner query syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting the same syntax error just about anything I tried on the following nested query on MySQL:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE_A AS A 
    WHERE A.COND = '2K' AND A.B_ID = : SELECT B.B_ID  
                                        FROM TABLE_B AS B
                                        WHERE B.NAME = 'XYZ';
```

Please note that the NAME column entries on TABLE_B are unique and no join is necessary as to the query logic.

How can I fix the syntax??

Naïve Q -- been long since native SQL.

TIA.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need parens around the subquery:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM TABLE_A AS A 
WHERE A.COND = '2K' AND
      A.B_ID = (SELECT B.B_ID  
                FROM TABLE_B AS B
                WHERE B.NAME = 'XYZ');
```

If it could return more than one value, then you would want `in` instead of `=`:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM TABLE_A AS A 
WHERE A.COND = '2K' AND
      A.B_ID IN (SELECT B.B_ID  
                 FROM TABLE_B AS B
                 WHERE B.NAME = 'XYZ');
```

Comment: worked. had 'unique' somewhere around there in that go between!

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the explicit subquery and use an explicit join instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT
  FROM TABLE_A AS A 
  JOIN TABLE_B AS B ON A.B_ID = B.B_ID
 WHERE A.COND = '2K'
   AND B.NAME = 'XYZ';
```

If you want the sub-query, then [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24276246/15168) is fine.

Comment: Join is not slow until you've measured it.  Your sub-query is probably transformed into a join by the optimizer anyway.